# product grid, items are with different height

Tags: html, css

Hello i'm working on a simple product grid for the moment only for testing it is not a final design or something and i have a problem with heights if i have a text on two rows the layout breaks and i've got no idea how to fix it googled around but didn't find anything first time i thought it was because of the picture.
Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pp6L8/9/

HTML:

```
<section class="shop-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="col-group">
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container ">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Product Name</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container ">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Product Name</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container ">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Product Name</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container ">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Biblioraft Plastifiat Globox Cotor 75Mm</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      </section>
    <section class="col-group">
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Product Name</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Product Name</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Product Name</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="http://www.scribant.ro/admin/cms_catalog/catalog_images/category_324/products/4654.jpg" alt=""></a>
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Product Name</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="item-actions">
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              <a href="" alt="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.product-name {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.product-name a {
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.shop-grid img {
    max-width: 258px;
    max-height: 258px;
}
.shop-grid .item-container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
.shop-grid .item-actions {
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.shop-grid .item-actions a {
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: none;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    z-index: 100;
}
.shop-grid .item-actions a [class^="icon-"], a [class*=" icon-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 9px;
}
.button {
    background: transparent;
    color: #555555;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #1695A3;
    color: #fff;
}
.col-group {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Replace this css...

```
.product-name {
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: can't i just write it like this ?
.product-name {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: and this could work but :-) if i go to 3 rows ( which might happen ) this would fail :D